# system of non-linear differential equations $x'=y^2$ and $y'=x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, nonlinear-system

I am working on Exercise 2.90 in Jeffrey M. Lee's book *Manifolds and Differential Geometry*. To solve it, I need to solve the following system of non-linear differential equations:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt}&=&y^{2} \\
\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt}&=&x^{2}
\end{array}
$$
Integrating the second equation and substitution into the first equation gives me
$$
dx=\left(\int{}x^{2}\,dt\right)^{2}dt
$$
but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Why can't you write $$\dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{x^2}{y^2}$$ Now this is Separable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah dang it. I was just writing that up as a hint @Moo. Good catch.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Sorry about that! :-)

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Cheers. I was writing this up and then saw Moo's comment.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to guess at the form of solutions.  I tried exponentials and products and that didn't seem to work.  Polynomials went nowhere.  But then I tried power functions.  A solution is $$ x = \frac{-1}{t}, y = \frac{-1}{t}$$

Comment: Your solution follows from Gregory's answer when $x^{3}=y^{3}$. For a more general solution we'd have to solve $$\int(x^{3}+C)^{-\frac{2}{3}}\,dx=t$$which honestly I don't know how to do offhand.

Comment: Looks like you'll end up with $x {}_2F_1(1/3, 2/3; 4/3; -x^3/C)/C^{2/3} + D = t$, but double-check my work.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than guess, you can also look at $dy/dx = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$ which leads to
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2}{y^2} \implies y^2 dy = x^2 dx \implies y^3 = x^3 + C. $$

Comment: And can we infer general solutions for $x$ and $y$ from this relationship between them?